# make target with same pattern twice

Tags: makefile

I have a bunch of libraries that I want to build as dependencies:

```
LIBS = libs/foo libs/bar
```

Each library has an object that I need to compile against, all in a predictable spot. They are:

```
libs/foo/lib/libfoo-O3.a
libs/bar/lib/libbar-O3.a
```

I would like to effectively transform my `LIBS` string into these rules:

```
build : libs/foo/lib/libfoo-O3.a libs/bar/lib/libbar-O3.a

libs/foo/lib/libfoo-O3.a:
    $(MAKE) -C libs/foo

libs/bar/lib/libbar-O3.a:
    $(MAKE) -C libs/bar
```

I know you can't use `%` twice, so unfortunately `libs/%/lib/lib%-O3.a` is a non-starter as a target. Is there another way to do this? Something with a `define` template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the LIBS variable to just contain the name, you can do it easily:

```
LIBS = foo bar

LIBPATHS := $(foreach L,$(LIBS),libs/$L/lib/lib$L-O3.a)
```

If you can't you can still do this, only slightly less readable:

```
LIBS = libs/foo libs/bar

LIBPATHS := $(foreach L,$(LIBS),$L/lib/lib$(notdir $L)-O3.a)
```

Then just add something like:

```
$(LIBPATHS):
        $(MAKE) -C $(firstword $(subst /lib/, ,$@))
```